# Loop through all the <script /> tags on a page

Tags: asp.net

I want to loop through all the referenced Javascript files on an ASP.Net page.

In other words, I want to enumerate all the

```
<script src="a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="b.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="c.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

tags on a page.

Of course, I can't do this because they are not actually visible to ASP.Net. They do not have a runat="server" tag on them. And, of course, if you add a runat="server" tag to them, then ASP.Net is going to actually try to run the javascript on the server (perhaps the only time where runat="server" has a real use!)

Am I out of luck here? I think I am, but it is worth asking.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? We might be able to help you find an alternative solution to the end-goal.

Comment: Do you want access to the pre-rendered page?

Comment: @RexM, I need to pass them to another control. There are definitely alternate ways to do this, I was choosing the laziest.

Comment: @CleverHuman ok, but why? What is the problem/purpose?

Comment: @RexM making an intelligent decision on what gets compressed / combined for each page. I felt like this was a distracting detail, because then all I would get is advice on alternate methods on how to accomplish my goal, instead of information that answered my specific question.

Comment: @CleverHuman I think (and based on the number of answers that solve your problem, the community agrees) that your approach is not ideal. I suggest backing up and diving in from a different angle.

Answer (score 2):

Are they all in the `<head>` of the page? If so make the head `runat=server`, then I'm pretty sure they become part of the `Page.Header.Controls` collection

Comment: This is true. Script tags inside a container with `runat=server` will become instances of [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) with a TagName of "script".

Comment: @Joel: Though it may not work if the scripts are added via ScriptManager.

Comment: If you add runat="server" to a script tag, ASP.Net will try to run that script tag server side.